# How to configure laravel parallel test to have same output as regular tests?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

When you run `php artisan test` the console output shows the result of every test per line, and errors are descriptive, showing you the exact line in the code that failed.

However when using `php artisan test --parallel` the output is different and if there are any errors it only shows the file that failed, not the line in the code.

Is it possible to configure `php artisan test --parallel` to have the same output as `php artisan test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass through commands to the underlying `phpunit` binary, and as long as they're understood by `paratest` they'll work. You can specify [TestDox output](https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest/pull/679) since last year. It doesn't change the output while testing, but does print the details afterwards.

```bash
artisan test --parallel --testdox
```

Comment: thanks! It looks better now, but not exactly as the output with regular tests. The colors are off and the output when there is an error doesn't show details of the code just the file and line number. 
Would there be a way to show the exact same output as `php artisan test`? I am on paratest 6.10

Comment: No, there is not (that I'm aware of)